# ArcObjects C# ArcMap toolbars to ArcGIS Pro

Tags: c#, arcgis-pro-sdk

I have some ArcMap toolbars written in ArcObjects C# using windows desktop controls/forms. They are very precise in terms of clients requirement.

How would I replicate them in ArcGIS Pro?

I have heard about WPF Dockpanes, and windows form. I do not know how to reference Windows forms in the Pro SDK solution.